# What's the answer to this limit question?

Tags: limits

Can anyone find the limit to this one?

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{i=(n+1)/2}^n {n \choose i} \times 0.51^i \times 0.49^{n-i})$

When I plot it, it seems to me to approach 1, which makes me *feel* that a limit should exist and it should be 1. But I can't solve this mathematically.

Here is the same question in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n+-%3E+infinity+%28%5Csum_%7Bi%3D%28n%2B1%29%2F2%7D%5En+%7Bn+choose+i%7D+0.51%5Ei*0.49%5E%7Bn-i%7D%29), in case it helps.

Comment: Just to be sure, the $0.51$ should'nt be raised to $i$, i.e. $0.51^i$?

Comment: @mickep, right. I fixed it now.

Comment: Do you know the Law of Large Numbers?

Comment: It looks a bit like the binomial expansion of $(0.51+0.49)^n$ if that helps.

Comment: @Hetebrij, I do but I don't see how it helps here.

Answer (score 4):

Consider tossing an unfair coin $2n-1$ times, where we assign the value $+1$ to head, which has probability $p=0.51$ and $-1$ to tails, with probability $0.49$. So we have a sequence of IID variables $X_1, \dots,X_{2n-1}$, and we denote the $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} X_i$. Furthermore, we have $$\mu = \mathbb{E} X_1 = 0.51 -0.49=0.02 >0 $$

Then we have $$ \mathbb{P}(S_n > 0)= \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{i} p^i (1-p)^{2n-1-i}.$$
So we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{i} p^i (1-p)^{2n-1-i} &=& \lim_{n \to \infty } \mathbb{P} ( S_n > 0) \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{S_n}{2n-1} > 0\right)\\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty } \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} X_i > 0 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now we can use the weak Law of Large Numbers and obtain
\begin{eqnarray} \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \left|\frac{1}{2n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{2n-1} X_i  - \mu \right| > \epsilon \right) = 0
\end{eqnarray}
for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So if we choose $\epsilon = \frac{\mu}{2}>0$, we have $$\left\{ \frac{S_n}{2n-1} \in \left( \frac{ \mu }{2} , \frac{ 3 \mu}{2} \right) \right\} \subset \left\{ \frac{ S_n}{2n-1} > 0 \right\}.$$
And therefore we find
\begin{eqnarray}
1 &\ge& \lim_{n \to \infty } \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{ S_n}{2n-1} >0 \right) \\ &\ge & \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{S_n}{2n-1 } \in \left( \frac{\mu}{2} , \frac{ 3 \mu }{2} \right) \right) \\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty } 1 - \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{S_n}{2n-1 } \not\in \left( \frac{\mu}{2} , \frac{ 3 \mu }{2} \right) \right) \\
&=& 1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \frac{ S_n}{2n-1} - \mu \right| > \frac{\mu}{2} \right) \\
&=& 1 -0 = 1
\end{eqnarray}

So combining everything we see $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{i} 0.51^p \times 0.49^{2n-1-i}=1$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Chebyshev's Inequality**

Since you have $\frac{n+1}2$ as a limit, let's work with odd $n=2m+1$.
$$
P(m)=\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{k}0.51^k0.49^{2m+1-k}
$$
Consider a [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with mean $0.51(2m+1)$ and variance $0.51\cdot0.49\ (2m+1)$.

$1-P(m)$ is the probability that $k\le m$, which is $\frac{0.02m+.51}{\sqrt{0.51\cdot0.49\ (2m+1)}}$ standard deviations below the mean.  [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) says that that probability is less than
$$
\frac{2499(2m+1)}{(2m+51)^2}
$$
Thus,
$$
1-\frac{2499(2m+1)}{(2m+51)^2}\le P(m)\le1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}P(m)=1
$$

---

**Approximating with the Gaussian**

When approximating a Binomial with the Gaussian, it is most accurate to run the integral from points half way between the integers. That is, to approximate $P(m)$, we would integrate above $m+\frac12$, which is $0.02m+0.01$ below the mean. Thus, we would compute the Gaussian above
$$
\frac{0.02m+.01}{\sqrt{0.51\cdot0.49\ (2m+1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{2m+1}{2499}}
$$
standard deviations below the mean or
$$
P(m)\approx\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{2m+1}{2499}}}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm{d}t
$$
The integral above tends to $1$.
$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|}
m&P(m)&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{2m+1}{2499}}}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm{d}t\\\hline
1&0.5149980000&0.5138197656\\
10&0.5369520990&0.5365198235\\
100&0.6117680778&0.6116437021\\
1000&0.8145669095&0.8145609488\\
10000&0.9976639732&0.9976657797
\end{array}
$$